# Xampp: Apache not working

Tags: apache2, xampp

I have a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installed. I installed Xampp, it worked fine.
I then installed VMware. Apache server stopped working in Xampp. I had a similar problem in Windows I changed the ports for 80 and 443. I am able to change the http port but not https, and can't find how to do it on the config file.

Comment: I changed the http port in httpd-ssl.conf and xampp file. 

Issue resolved

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu, freedom and Linux! Glad you fixed it...

Comment: Please consider writing an answer about how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the http port in the following two files:

```
/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
```